# C# to C++ Polymorphism

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I had in C# an array of my custom class Entity. Due to different types of entities which I created and the way C# polymorphism worked, I chose to keep the different entity types in one entity array (i.e. I had the Player entity in the Entity array, the Enemy entity, etc.). However, in C++, using a vector of Entities, when i declare a unique Entity such as a Player, it seems to lose all the values it has as a Player, maintaining only those it has as an Entity. Is this an oversight on my part, or are the rules of polymorphism different in C++? How can I fix this?

Comment: Show us your code.  Make sure you indent it four spaces, or use the `{}` button above the editor window to indent it.

Comment: Could be that placing an object into a vector causes a copy and your copy constructor is not up to the task.

Comment: C++ Managed (CLI) or Unmanaged code ?   How are you "talking" to C++?

Answer (score 2):

### Object slicing in C++

Sometimes also called the slicing problem, occurs if a superclass instance is assigned its **value** from a subclass instance, member variables defined in the subclass cannot be copied, since the superclass has no place to store them. This only happens when you pass objects by value. As Kornel [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825249/961781), a way around this is to use vectors of pointers to objects.

See the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) for a nice code example. Better yet this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c), explains in more details the subtle bugs that can be caused by accidental slicing

Answer (score 0):

In C# everything is a "reference" to an object by default. In C++ you'd need to use a pointer in the vector ( e.g. `vector< Entity* >` ) or a smart pointer ( `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` ) of your choice, to show that you're referring to the entities by themselves, and not by value.

Otherwise, the space allocated for each of your entities is the same, hence loosing any additional information.

Comment: In attempting to do this, my GetEntities function broke. I changed its type to vector<Entity*> and I get the error:
error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(const std::vector<_Ty> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'

Comment: If you want to get all of them, the function retrieving them should be `const std::vector< Entities* >& GetEntities() const { return m_entities }"`

Comment: If m_entities in your example is my vector<Entity*>, I get an error just like the one I showed above.

Comment: have you included the `const` and `&` for the return value?

Comment: It is just like this: vector<Entity*>& Level::GetEntities() const

Comment: If you return from a method that is marked `const`, the return value also needs to be marked either `const` or not be a reference.

Comment: The error persists regardless of the const; with the const, it simply changes to "cannot convert from const std::vector<_Ty> to std::vector<_Ty> &

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very stupid. Any error beyond your 2nd comment was due to my idiocy. Thanks for the help!